# Creating BranchInst in llvm

Tags: llvm, llvm-ir

When trying this code snippet, opt runs fine but when trying to run llvm-dis-11, I get an error `Instruction invalid with no BB`. The error has to do with the BranchInst in the code snippet that I was trying to insert before the ret instruction.

The code snippet

```
struct custom_func2 : public PassInfoMixin<custom_func2>
{
    llvm::PreservedAnalyses run(Function &F, FunctionAnalysisManager &FAM)
    {
        if(F.getName() == "main")
        {
            llvm::BasicBlock& main_block = F.getEntryBlock();
            llvm::Instruction *ret_instr = main_block.getTerminator();
            llvm::BranchInst *branch_instr = llvm::BranchInst::Create(&main_block, ret_instr);
        }

        return llvm::PreservedAnalyses:all();
    }
};
```

opt output (which ran fine)

```
%3 = alloca i32, align 4
%4 = alloca i32, align 4
%5 = alloca i8**, align 8
store i32 0, i32* %3, align 4
store i32 %0, i32* %4, align 4
store i8** %1, i8*** %5, align 8
br label %2 <-------------------- Trying to insert this instruction here
ret i32 0
```

Any advice on how to resolve this is appreciated.

**EDIT 8 Dec 2020**

I made some changes to see if a different way works but this time round, the new instruction does not get inserted.

```
struct custom_func2 : public PassInfoMixin<custom_func2>
{
    llvm::PreservedAnalyses run(Function &F, FunctionAnalysisManager &FAM)
    {
        if(F.getName().str() == "main")
        {
            llvm::Function *main_func = &F;
            
            for(BasicBlock &BB : F)
            {
                for(Instruction &I : BB)
                {
                    if(isa<StoreInst>(&I))
                    {
                        llvm::CallInst *call_instr = llvm::CallInst::Create(main_func, None, "", &I);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        return llvm::PreservedAnalyses:all();
    }
};
```

Comment: You can't have two terminators in one block. Both `br` and `ret` are terminators. The error message seems poorly worded, or perhaps you also have another issue, and the message pertains to that other issue.

Comment: And the way to resolve almost every problem is to call Verifier::verifyModule() at the end of anything that performs a change and might be buggy. Verify early and often, and remove the call only when you're satisfied that your code is dependable.

Comment: Hi @arnt

I tried making some changes by inserting call instructions instead but ran into another problem. It seems that I was not able to insert new instructions based on the code.